# Cannot read property stop of undefined - when calling a static method from inside class

Tags: javascript, class

For some reason, when I run this code, even without first calling the startRecording method it gives me this error right after the page has loaded.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read proporty 'stop' of undefind.

I think it has something to do with scope but I'm not sure. The startRecording method works fine but it finds a problem in stopRecording.

**RecorderClass**

```
class RecorderClass
{
    constructor() {
        this.rec = ''
    }

    static startRecording() {
        this.rec = new Recorder()
        this.rec.record()
    }

    static stopRecording() {
        this.rec.stop() // stop() of undefined
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
import RecorderClass from './RecorderClass.js'
recButton.addEventListener("click", RecorderClass.startRecording())
```

Comment: Were do you call `stopRecording` ? As a sidenote: the constructor - and the class as a whole - is superflouos if you don't constrcut an instance.

Comment: `recButton.addEventListener("click", RecorderClass.startRecording())` - This does not what you might think it does.

Comment: First of all, you need to create an instance of the RecorderClass `let record = new RecorderClass()`. And then you can use it like `recButton.addEventListener("click", record.startRecording())`

Comment: @oliver.voron now it is saying that this.rec.stop is not a function

Comment: @oliver.voron nope.

Comment: what is there in the Recorder class. new Recorder()??

Answer (score 0):

You should declare Recorder reference in the scope of class, so that stop recording method can use it.

```
 public class RecorderClass
{
    static Recorder rec;
    public RecorderClass()
    {
    }

    public static void startRecording()
    {
        rec = new Recorder();
        rec.record();
    }

    public static void stopRecording()
    {
        rec.stop();// stop() of undefined
    }
}
```