# Getting undefined when using public class property

Tags: javascript, class

This is truly strange and I cannot understand why this is happening. When I call the `startRecording()` method it works perfectly and I can test that `this.rec` has been set. But then when I call `stopRecording()` method it says that `this.rec` is undefined. How can this be if I know that it is defined?

The problem is in `RecorderClass.js` when I call the `stopRecording()` method.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <button id="recordButton">Record</button>
            <button id="stopButton">Stop</button>
        </div>

        <script src="recorder.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
import RecorderClass from './RecorderClass.js'

let recordButton = document.getElementById("recordButton")
let stopButton = document.getElementById("stopButton")

let RecorderObject = new RecorderClass()

recordButton.addEventListener("click", RecorderObject.startRecording)
stopButton.addEventListener("click", RecorderObject.stopRecording)
```

**RecorderClass.js**

```
class RecorderClass
{
    startRecording()
    {
        this.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext

        let constraints = { audio: true, video: false }

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(stream => {
            let audioContext    = new AudioContext()
            this.gumStream       = stream
            let input           = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
            this.rec             = new Recorder(input, { numChannels: 1 })
            this.rec.record()
        })

        // Returns an object !!!!!
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(this.rec)
        }, 3000)
    }

    stopRecording()
    {
        // Returns undefined !!!!!
        console.log(this.rec)

        this.rec.stop()
        this.gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop()
    }
}

export default RecorderClass
```

Here is the project on CodePen (you can see the error in console)

https://codepen.io/martinszeltins/project/editor/ZBWJoN

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property stop of undefined - when calling a static method from inside class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142485/cannot-read-property-stop-of-undefined-when-calling-a-static-method-from-insid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are losing the `this` reference here:

```
recordButton.addEventListener("click", RecorderObject.startRecording)
stopButton.addEventListener("click", RecorderObject.stopRecording)
```

You pass the function reference as callback to `addEventListener`. When the event happens, that callback is called without any particular `this` binding.

You should instead do:

```
recordButton.addEventListener("click", () => RecorderObject.startRecording())
stopButton.addEventListener("click", () => RecorderObject.stopRecording())
```

Now these methods are called on your object, which serves as `this` during the call.

NB: it would be good to name your instance objects with an initial lowercase letter, as initial capitals are commonly used for constructors/classes.